# How to "grep" lines with html tags from a sql text field?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

A mysql table contains more than 74000 entries in a field named "body" of type text.

I need a view with only contains lines that contain HTML tags.

Example:

Record 1 =>

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://foo.bar">consetetur</a> sadipscing elitr\n
sed diam nonumy eirmod temporary invidunt ut labore et dolore\n
<hr>
aliquyam magna erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

Record 2 =>

```
At vero eos et <strong>accusam</strong> et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.\n
Stet clita kasd gubergren, No sea takimata sanctus est Lorem\n
ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Record = 3>

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr\n
<ul><li>sed</li> <li>diam</li></ul> nonumy eirmod temporary invidunt ut labore et dolore\n
aliquyam magna erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

The output should contain only the rows with the HTML tags:

Record 1 =>

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://foo.bar">consetetur</ a> sadipscing elitr\n
```

Record 2 =>

```
At vero eos et <strong>accusam</strong> et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.\n
```

Record 3 =>

```
<ul><li>sed</li> <li>diam</li></ul> nonumy eirmod temporary invidunt ut labore et dolore\n
```

I need the output for manual review by a script run.

Does anyone have an idea for a corresponding sql select statement, e.g.

```
SELECT `body` FROM `messages` WHERE `body` REGEXP -> `<regexp_for_html-tags_here>`;
```

or something like this.

regards

Comment: Is there a possibility that texts in `body` will contain "<", but it will not be tag? If not, then just make a query with `WHERE body LIKE '%<%'`. It will work faster.

Comment: You can try what Sanja said above, but to be more sure, try to do WHERE body LIKE '%<%' and body LIKE '%>%' this can make your query little bit safer

Comment: yes, the body contain "<" and ">", but not as html tags. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex you could do something like this:

```
SELECT body 
FROM messages 
WHERE body REGEXP '.*<[:alpha:][:alnum:]*.*>.*';
```

**EDIT**

In the comments some have mentioned performance.  You may be able to use a combination of LIKE and REGEXP to improve performance - i.e. the like statement will narrow the data to the interesting rows, then the REGEXP can refine the search (e.g. to avoid issues where these characters appear but not as potential tag names).

```
SELECT body 
FROM messages 
WHERE body like '%<%>%' 
and body REGEXP '.*<[:alpha:][:alnum:]*.*>.*';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70c47/2

Comment: NB: you can improve upon the given regex; so far I've come up with the following; still tweaking though: `where body REGEXP '.*<([:alpha:][:alnum:]*)[:space:]*([:alpha:][:alnum:][:space:]*=[:space:]*([\'"]).*$3[:space:]*)*(/>)|(>.*</$1>).*'`

Comment: your 1st example works, but shows me >3600 records. there are many records which contains <%> but not as html tag. so i need to reduce the result once more.

Comment: Sadly it seems backreferences aren't available in MySQL's version of Regex, so my attempt in the comments won't work / it's impossible to get this entirely locked down.  However I suspect someone more familiar with regex than myself could provide a better solution - ask another question on here saying "mysql regex for identifying tags in text" and someone's bound to have a solution for you.  Sorry I can't be more help on this one.